# JS, How to select all rows data of serverside DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have 2 pages of serverside Datatable and I want to select all rows data from all pages

[image]

And this code

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    /*
        Some code
    */
})

var data = table.rows().data()
console.log(data)
```

returns the data of selected page only ( in this case the data of 1st page )

So, is it possible to select all data from all pages for ***serverside DataTables*** ?

Comment: hi, i need to do same, did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. If you use remote paging, the client doesn't know anything about other pages records yet.

According to [documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/select.html) to select all records for local paging. You could use

```
table.rows().select()
```

In same way, if you want to deselect them just try like this.

```
table.rows().deselect();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `"All"` option to `lengthMenu` drop-down like below code:

```
lengthMenu: [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ],
```

[image: show NN entries]

so the user can show all the data on one page, then do the filtering and search and select all the data which is needed.
`lengthMenu` is one of the datatable properties that could be modified based on your needs.